# How much time do I have to recover for a football match after intense bicycling for 6 hours as a delivery person?

Tags: exercise, recovery, bicycling, football

I am working as a Uber Eats in my bicycle this work is really intense I need to be faster than my competitors with motorbikers, fast for my competitors no take my orders.

I really like this job because keep me fit and in constant training and also working, but **I don't understand how to measure my recovery for a football match or futsal.** **Can someone help me?** For example after a long road of 6 hours of working 1 day when is the ideal day for do a football match? assuming that with this work day I have trained enough to be physically prepared for a match. I think this kind of question can be applicable for every sports.